# Is there a standalone Nixpkgs “standard library” to create private Nixpkgs repos?

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

Is there any project/repo that contains "standard library" functions extracted from the Nixpkgs repo?

Currently reading the Nixpkgs manual, and it seems that the Nixpkgs repo consists of

- functions that actually help build (cross-platform) packages (written using the Nix `builtin`'s/primitives)
- collection of packages

Tried to find decentralization examples, but there aren't many (or I didn't find them). I like Cachix and the philosophy behind it, but that is for already built packages (unless I misunderstand something, which is more than possible).

Some of the resources found:

- [Managing private Nix packages outside the Nixpkgs tree](http://sandervanderburg.blogspot.com/2014/07/managing-private-nix-packages-outside.html) [Sander van der Burg]
- [I create a local repository for NixOS/nixpkgs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183440/how-do-i-create-a-local-repository-for-nixos-nixpkgs) [Unix/Linux Stack Exchange]

---

EDIT: Just found out about [Nix User Repository (NUR)](https://github.com/nix-community/NUR).

EDIT2: Here's [the thread on NixOS discourse](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nixpkgs-standard-library/2753).

Comment: I don't see what the problem is with doing `(import <nixpkgs>).usefulFunction` or the equivalent in your own repo.

Comment: @DavidGrayson To quote parkerhoyes: "[_Just experimenting, really._](https://www.reddit.com/r/NixOS/comments/e417gy/using_nix_without_nixpkgs/f9643lp?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nixpkgs is a "megarepo", bundling highly related Nix projects, such as Nixpkgs, its standard library, NixOS and such. I am not aware of any other source or 'mirror' of these projects. If you want this to change, you can help out with the Nix Flakes idea/project/projects.

Today, if you only really need `pkgs.lib`, you can use `lib = import <nixpkgs/lib>`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding years later, that inspired for by this post I found that for a flake, you can use:

```
{
  inputs = { nixpkgs.url = "nixpkgs"; };
  outputs = { nixpkgs, ...} :
  let 
    lib = nixpkgs.lib;
    something = lib.mapAttrs f somelist;
  in {
    lib.something;

  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Ashamed to admit, but I still haven't used flakes (not even in production deployments I manage...), even though they are the future, and there are more and more projects that offer this kind of dependency granularity (e.g., [flakestry.dev announcement](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/announcing-flakestry-dev-new-registry-for-flakes/34583), [FlakeHub](https://flakehub.com/)).